# use gpu to accelerate data preprocessing in google colab (Python)

Tags: model, gpu, google-colaboratory, preprocessor, training-data

I am trying to train my model. The input data consists of similar patches. Generating similar patches (8x8x10) function takes a very long time, even when Colab is connected to a GPU (but not used).

```
Patches_label = img_to_Patches(images_label, sP, nSP, offset)
# This line takes very long
Patches_in = SearchSimilarPatches(images_in, sP, nSP, sW, offset)

history = model.fit(Patches_in, Patches_label, steps_per_epoch=2000, epochs=400, verbose=1, initial_epoch=initial_epoch, callbacks=[checkpointer,csv_logger,lr_scheduler])
```

Colab notified me that I am connected to a GPU, but it is not in use.

How can I make sure Colab is using GPU for data preprocessing?